# Unregister from GCM and register on FCM

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

My android app uses GCM and urbanairship for push notifications.

Now Google has deprecated GCM and is recommending to switch to FCM.

The problem is I don't have access to the Google account which was used to set up GCM as it was set up using one of the developers account who has left. So I can not migrate from GCM to FCM as told in the migration tutorials.

In this scenario, how can I switch to FCM using a different Google account keeping in mind that I use urbanairship?
I want to preserve the registration tokens, or get them replaced without asking customers to uninstall and reinstall the app.

Is it possible that the app registers itself with FCM when I roll down an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem:
1. Created a new Google FCM account.
2. Created a new project in Urbanairship console using keys from new Google FCM account.
3. Updated the backend code to send notifications twice - once for old urbanairship project and once for new project. Out of the two attempts, one will fail for sure and one will succeed for sure as customer will be using either of the two versions of the app.
4. Customers using old version of app will have registation tokens which are available with old urbanairship project. Customers using new version of app will have registation tokens which are available with new urbanairship project.
5. When customer updates the app, urbanairship takes care of registering the token with new FCM account server. I don't have to do anything here. This was not expected as token is updated upon fresh installation and not during updates.

So to summarize:
UA Project Old -> Google GCM -> Device with old app version
UA Project New -> Google FCM -> Device with new app version

Answer (score 1):

> *The problem is I don't have access to the Google account which was used to set up GCM as it was set up using one of the developers account who has left.*

This is not an uncommon situation. What I would suggest is contacting [Google Support](https://support.google.com/code/contact/gcm_dev_support) about the GCM Project. It would be best for you to get access to current project, specially if you are the one managing/using it.

After getting access, you could then migrate it to Firebase as needed.

> *In this scenario, how can I switch to FCM using a different Google account keeping in mind that I use urbanairship?*

You can't switch to a different account. However, you could modify your app to receive messages from a different project. I haven't used UrbanAirship before, but AFAIK, if they are using GCM underneath their service, then they too should be handling the FCM migration part.

> *Is it possible that the app registers itself with FCM when I roll down an update?*

In order to *register* an app is for it to call `getToken()`. So technically, yes. But you would have to handle pairing/saving the token to it's corresponding user.

With all that said, I would strongly suggest you contact Google Support first.

Comment: I contacted google support, waiting for their reply. UrbanAirship requires me to migrate my GCM project to FCM along with their sdk update. I get most of the part of your answer, a few questions - I can modify my app to receive messages from different projects, can you point how?

Comment: Google said that if you have not migrated to FCM, they can not help as they do not have any visibility into the project. They said to contact Google Cloud Support which requires project id. I do not have the project id.

Comment: Your Sender ID counts as the Project ID.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [FCM Urban Airship migration guide.](https://github.com/urbanairship/android-library/blob/master/documentation/migration/migration-guide-fcm.md) Assuming you are able to recover your GCM account you only need to follow that guide with your existing sender ID. If you change accounts, you will have to configure the new FCM project API key in the Urban Airship dashboard. The SDK will automatically update all the channels with the new registration token. During the transition period, only devices that have updated will be able to receive push.

Comment: I was not able to recover the account.